# Namenode keeps shutting down after start-dfs.sh

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, ubuntu-18.04

### Namenode for Fully Distributed Hadoop in Ubuntu mode will not stay open/  It starts and shutsdown with the error below.  I tried a few things but nothing works.  The namenode log is below and it automatically shuts down.  Any help is appreciated.

Directory /usr/hdfs/namenode is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.
2019-03-25 01:34:44,354 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at

I have already tried reformatting namenode

7952 SecondaryNameNode
7714 DataNode
23346 NodeManager
10555 Jps
23167 ResourceManager

Answer (score 0):

kindly recheck files vim ~/.bashrc, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml